# How to make FormControl retain its selected value on page refresh

Tags: reactjs

```
<FormControl componentClass="select" onChange={handleOptionSelect} value={this.state.selected}>
    <option value="default"></option>
    <option value="getasinlimit">Get ASIN Limit</option>
    <option value="updateasinlimit">Create/Update ASIN Limit</option>
    <option value="deleteasinlimit">Delete ASIN Limit</option>
</FormControl>
```

Is there a way I can programmatically set the value of a selected form in reactjs?

If I choose any of the option other than "default" and refresh the page, the route and page content stays the same but the selected option goes back to default. I want it to stay the same on page refresh. Is there a way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use session storage to save the selected value

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected : null;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let selected = window.sessionStorage.getItem("selected");
    this.setState({ selected : selected });
  }

  handleOptionSelect(e){
    this.setState({ selected : e.target.value });
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("selected", e.target.value);
  }

  render() {

      return (
        <FormControl componentClass="select" onChange={this.handleOptionSelect.bind(this)} value={this.state.selected}>
          <option value="default"></option>
          <option value="getasinlimit">Get ASIN Limit</option>
          <option value="updateasinlimit">Create/Update ASIN Limit</option>
          <option value="deleteasinlimit">Delete ASIN Limit</option>
        </FormControl>
      )

  }
}
```

Comment: What if I want it to reset when I do path change? If I use sessionStorage it will retain its value when I go to a different route

Comment: You can reset or clear the value in other component where you are navigating. 
Suppose you are navigating from login page to dashboard page, you the clear the session storage value in componentDidMount of dashboard component like this 
`window.sessionStorage.removeItem('selected');`

Comment: other else you can override the previous value
`window.sessionStorage.setItem('selected', newValue);`

Answer (score 0):

Put it in sessionStorage.

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

or localStorage if you want to retain the value when coming back even after closing the browser

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
var cat = localStorage.getItem("myCat");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage